# Meta analysis of continuous outcome but different follow up time

Tags: meta-analysis, continuous-data

I am looking at different studies and the outcome is a percent reduction from baseline. The studies all have different follow up times. If I simply control for follow up time, that may be biased since my outcome doesn't follow a linear pattern.

Would you have any suggestions as to whether it is appropriate to do a meta-analysis in such cases? If yes, which methods would you recommend?

Comment: You are not forced to put follow-up time in as a moderator in a linear way, you can choose any function you want.

Comment: How would you recommend doing the meta-analysis?

Comment: As you suggested, add follow-up time as a a moderator. If you suspect the relationship is non-linear and you have plenty of primary studies then add follow-up in some non-linear way (splines, transformed, polynomial, ...).

Answer (score 1):

Just to ensure this does not go answered here are my comments converted into an answer.

If you are concerned that the moderator has a non-linear relationship with the effect sizes you are modelling in your meta-analysis then you can enter it into the analysis in a non-linear way. You might use splines, which are very flexible, or polynomials of low degree if you are convinced a polynomial is a suitable function.